# Is there any work arounds with sending value to php file using socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am trying to send a value with socket.io to a php file. I know that node.js will not interpret a PHP file.. I was just wondering if there any work around for this

```
    var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

});



app.get('/order_management.php', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/order_management.php');
});



io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){

        io.emit('chat message', msg);
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
});





http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.  "sending value to php file using socket.io" makes no sense.  Please describe in regular words what you are trying to accomplish.  A PHP file is just that, a file.  You could have a server that could run PHP and using a PHP file as the code to run, but I don't see that anywhere in  your code.  What are you actually trying to do?  Furthermore, you send data using socket.io to a client that has connected to your server via socket.io (no PHP involved at all).

Comment: Instead of using node.js, why not use PHP? There is a socket.io library for PHP: https://github.com/Wisembly/elephant.io

Comment: @slebetman I  tried that but it seems very complicated and there is no documentation that explains how to use it

Comment: Hmm. Sorry that appears to be a client library, not a server. I guess the alternative is to use child_process.exec etc. to execute php directly `php your_php_file.php` like how you would do it on the command line. Then you can either pass the variables as arguments or try to pretend to be a web server by emulating CGI protocol (google cgi spec). CGI basically pass things by setting env variables

Comment: Its alright. I am cam across this other library on git hub that looks a lot easier to use. It called https://github.com/Devristo/phpws. But the issue my local host d